# how can i in c convert a very big hex number into an array of decimal?

Tags: c, types, hex, bitwise-operators, largenumber

how can i in c convert a very big hex number into an array of decimals?

```c
unsigned char hexnr[32]={0xa5,0xe0,0x43,0xe4,0x10,0xb7,0x3a,0x7e,0xdf,0xba,0xec,0x78,0x52,0x82,0xfd,0xd2,0xea,0x43,0xec,0x53,0xdb,0x24,0xbc,0xdd,0xbb,0x5d,0x2c,0xc4,0x45,0x98,0xad,0x16};
                     
                    
char ResultInDecimals[]={7,5,0,2,7,8,6,2,3,2,4,3,8,2,7,5,9,7,4,8,5,4,6,3,7,0,0,5,2,4,2,8,7,7,3,5,3,6,8,3,3,3,8,0,8,1,9,0,5,7,1,1,6,5,1,9,1,5,2,0,5,5,4,7,0,7,8,7,6,2,5,7,9,0,7,4,2};
```

in hex : `0xa5e043e410b73a7edfbaec785282fdd2ea43ec53db24bcddbb5d2cc44598ad16`

out decimal : `75027862324382759748546370052428773536833380819057116519152055470787625790742`

Comment: Use Gnu Bignum library.

Comment: It's really not clear what you want to do here. Are the two arrays that you have shown supposed to represent the same data? If so, how?

Comment: Allocate an array A large enough to contain the result. Initialize it is zero. For each two-hexadecimal-digit element, multiply the contents of A by 256 using the multiplication algorithm you were taught in elementary school, where you multiply each digit in the array by each digit in 256 and add them together, shifted to appropriate positions, and then add the new two-hexadecimal-digit element (convert it to a three-digit decimal number, and add it to the array using the addition algorithm you were taught in elementary school).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you Eric il try that now

Comment: @AdrianMole, that's right, those two arrays represent the same data

Comment: What representation is the result array supposed to be? Do you really want numbers, not characters?

Comment: You need to reserve about 2.5 decimal digits per byte, rounding up to a whole number of digits. (2.5 is an overestimate but is easy to calculate. You actually need to reserve log10(256) decimal digits per byte, rounding up to a whole number of digits.)

Comment: Just to make things clear: what decimal array would you get with `0x1234`? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: @Gerhardh , the representation of the second array `ResultInDecimals[]` stores the conversion of the entire hex `0xa5e043e410b73a7edfbaec785282fdd2ea43ec53db24bcddbb5d2cc44598ad16`

and  stores it in an array of numbers

Comment: That does not really explain much. Is this supposed to be a decimal representation of that converted number with each `char` storing a decimal digit?

Comment: @Gerhardh if you convert the hexstring the output decimal number is very big there is no type to store such a huge number so i have to take piece by piece and store it in an array that represents the large decimal number witch is `75027862324382759748546370052428773536833380819057116519152055470787625790742 `

Comment: To save space in the output array, you could store it as two decimal digits per byte (1 digit per 4-bit nybble, i.e. BCD (binary-coded decimal) format), or store it in base 100.

Comment: @IanAbbott "To save space in the output array..." i just came across that exactly problem right now gona try to store it as base 100"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic operation is to divide the 32-digit base 256 number with 10 and get the remainder.

From the result, I notice that both the "hex" number and the result are stored with the most significant digit first. Hence the division method can be implemented as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

// Divide 256-base number in "hex" by 10 and return remainder
unsigned char div10(unsigned char *hex, unsigned size)
{
    unsigned rem = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        unsigned n = rem * 256 + hex[i];
        hex[i] = n / 10;
        rem = n % 10;
    }
    return rem;
}
```

Applying this to the given example can be done like this:

```
unsigned char hexnr[32]={0xa5,0xe0,0x43,0xe4,0x10,0xb7,0x3a,0x7e,0xdf,0xba,0xec,0x78,0x52,0x82,0xfd,0xd2,0xea,0x43,0xec,0x53,0xdb,0x24,0xbc,0xdd,0xbb,0x5d,0x2c,0xc4,0x45,0x98,0xad,0x16};  // Most significant digit first

unsigned char result[80]={0};  // Fixed 80 digits

char ResultInDecimals[]={7,5,0,2,7,8,6,2,3,2,4,3,8,2,7,5,9,7,4,8,5,4,6,3,7,0,0,5,2,4,2,8,7,7,3,5,3,6,8,3,3,3,8,0,8,1,9,0,5,7,1,1,6,5,1,9,1,5,2,0,5,5,4,7,0,7,8,7,6,2,5,7,9,0,7,4,2};   // Known result for comparison


int main(void)
{
    unsigned char hexzero[32] = {0};
    unsigned i = 0;
    while(memcmp(hexnr, hexzero, sizeof(hexnr)) != 0 && i < sizeof(result))
    {
        result[sizeof(result) - i - 1] = div10(hexnr, sizeof(hexnr));
        i++;
    }

    if(memcmp(hexnr, hexzero, sizeof(hexnr)) != 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: result buffer too small\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < sizeof(result); j++)
        {
            printf("%c", result[j]+'0');
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

which prints the result:

```
00075027862324382759748546370052428773536833380819057116519152055470787625790742
```